# Angular 2 - Wait for Promise before continuing

Tags: angular, promise, angular-promise

I'm need to create a geolocation variable and send the values to an API but I'm trouble.

```
public virtualRegistrationHandler(e: any): void {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("loop");
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        let geoLoc = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setGeoLoc);

        this.VirtualRegistrationService.virtualRegistration(geoLoc)
            .subscribe(
            response => this.toastyCommunicationService.addSuccesResponseToast(response),
            error => this.toastyCommunicationService.addErrorResponseToast(error)
            );
    } else {
        this.toastyCommunicationService.addErrorResponseToast("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

private setGeoLoc(position: any) {
    console.log("Latitude " + position.coords.latitude, "Longitude " + position.coords.longitude);
    let geoLoc = { "Latitude": position.coords.latitude, "Longitude": position.coords.longitude };
    return geoLoc;
}
```

this is my current code, but it doesn't wait for `geoLoc` to be returned, so right now it sends an undefined parameter to the API.

I want to API call to wait untill `geoloc` is set.

I did some googling and I came accros promises, however I'm having trouble writing the syntax and I cant find any working example.

How do I correctly write my code so that geoLoc has to be set first before my function continues to the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition), The getCurrentPosition method returns a promise, So you only need to subscribe to it.

Something like :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    pos=>{
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
    },
    onError=>{
    ...Catch errors...
    }
    );
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track, however `"Latitude": position.coords.latitude` it says it doesn't know what `position` is, how do I get this value then?

Comment: The resove function should hold an object of type position (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Position). Iv'e edited my answer so it will be more clear

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` call to Promise:

```
const whenPositionGet = new Promise((resolve, reject) => navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject));
whenPositionGet.then(
  (position: Position) => {
      console.log("Latitude " + position.coords.latitude, "Longitude " + position.coords.longitude);
  },
  (error: PositionError) => {
      console.error(error);
  }
);
```